# Dynamically applying validation in an MVC EditorTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, unobtrusive-validation, data-annotations

The problem - I am tasked with replicating an old Web Forms application in MVC.  I have been asked to keep the markup similar.  I have no idea why, but there you go.  So, what would generally be a simple label and textbox becomes

```
<td>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id='@Model.Label' class='MILabel'>
                    @Model.Name
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="NoWrap">
                <span id='@Model.Prefix' class='Prefix'>@Model.Prefix</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td class="SetDivInputWidth">
    <div id='@Model.DivId' class="NoWrap">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Value, new
        {
            @id = Model.Name,
            @onkeyup = Model.OnKeyUp,
            @class = Model.FullClass,
            @maxlength = "100"
        }.DisabledIf(Model.IsDisabled))
        @{
            if (Model.HasGuidanceNote)
            {
                <img class="GuidanceNote" src='~/Content/Images/info.png' alt='Notes'
                     onmouseover="@Model.GuidanceNotesMouseOver"
                     onmouseout="@Model.GuidanceNotesMouseOut" />

                <span id="@Model.GuidanceNotesIdentifier" class='Info'>@Model.GuidanceNote</span>
            }}

        <img class="ErrorIcon" alt='' src='@Model.ErrorImage' id="@Model.ErrorImageId" onmouseover="@Model.ErrorImageMouseOver" onmouseout="@Model.ErrorImageMouseOut" />
        <div class="WarningText" id="@Model.WarningDivId"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

which is a custom EditorTemplate for a basic implementation of

```
public class MyTextField
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isReadOnly;

    public string Label
    {
        get { return Name + "Label"; }
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    public string FullClass
    {
        get { return CssClass + " " + Readonly; }
    }

    public string Readonly
    {
        get
        {
            return _isReadOnly ? "MIReadOnly" : String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Disabled { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public bool HasGuidanceNote
    {
        get { return (GuidanceNote != null); }
    }

    public bool IsReadonly
    {
        get { return _isReadOnly; }
        set
        {
            _isReadOnly = value;
        }
    }

    public string OnKeyUp
    {
        get { return "Fields.callOnChange('" + Name + "');"; }
    }

    public string ErrorImage { get; set; }

    public string ErrorImageId
    {
        get { return Name + "ErrorIcon"; }
    }

    public string ErrorImageMouseOver
    {
        get { return "Utils.showErrorText('" + Name + "')"; }
    }

    public string ErrorImageMouseOut
    {
        get { return "Utils.clearErrorText('" + Name + "')"; }
    }

    public string DivId
    {
        get { return Name + "Div"; }
    }

    public string WarningDivId
    {
        get { return Name + "ErrorText"; }
    }

    public string GuidanceNote { get; set; }

    public string GuidanceNotesIdentifier
    {
        get { return Name + "GuidanceNotes"; }
    }

    public string GuidanceNotesMouseOver
    {
        get { return "Utils.showGuidanceNote('" + GuidanceNotesIdentifier + "')"; }
    }

    public string GuidanceNotesMouseOut
    {
        get { return "Utils.clearGuidanceNote('" + GuidanceNotesIdentifier + "')"; }
    }
}
```

And this is all fine.  In fact, it's great.

The problem arises due to complex validation of various fields.  Obviously, I'm having to create instances of MyTextField (not its real name) in a viewmodel, populate the relevant fields for the editor and then display using the EditorTemplate.

But I can't use DataAnnotations to validate my data for this because each MyTextBox will have different validation rules.  Some might be mandatory fields, some might not.  Some will only allow certain inputs, others are not validated at all.  Som rely on other fields on the same View - others don't.

Does anyone have any advice or should I resign myself to manually validating everything with JavaScript?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Note: you only need to use @ on html attributes that conflict with c# names, such as @class, don't use @ for id, onkeyup, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer that I'm fairly happy with.

Here's one of my Display classes on which I've used implicit operator to make it effectively a string.

```
public class RubikTextBox : AbstractField, IAbstractField
{
    public RubikTextBox(string val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(RubikTextBox stringValue)
    {
        return stringValue.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator RubikTextBox(string stringValue)
    {
        return new RubikTextBox(stringValue);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

And it inherits some stuff that contain other properties, the abstract class particularly is for spitting out div IDs and stuff and generally saving me time and code.

Now, the EditorTemplate that emits HTML for this beast look like this -

```
<td>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id='@Model.LabelName' class='MILabel'>
                    @Model.Label
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="NoWrap">
                <span id='@Model.PrefixName' class='Prefix'>@Model.Prefix</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td class="SetDivInputWidth">
    <div id='@Model.DivId' class="NoWrap">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new
        {
            id = Model.Name,
            @class = Model.CssClass,
            maxlength = "100"
        }.DisabledIf(Model.IsDisabled).ReadOnlyIf(Model.IsReadonly))
        @{
            if (Model.HasGuidanceNote)
            {
                <img class="GuidanceNote" src='~/Content/Images/info.png' alt='Notes'
                     onmouseover="@Model.GuidanceNotesMouseover"
                     onmouseout="@Model.GuidanceNotesMouseOut" />

                <span id="@Model.GuidanceNoteName" class='Info'>@Model.GuidanceNote</span>
            }}
    </div>
</td>
```

The really important line here is

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m
```

And that's because in the viewmodel that's the source for this property, I can do the following -

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = @"Must be completed")]
public RubikTextBox MatterNumber { get; set; }
```

So the complex class acts like a string and the default implicit property is the one that's validated by the DataAnnotation.

And just to prove it, the HTML that's emitted is (according to F12 tools)

```
<input name="MatterNumber" id="MatterNumber" type="text" value="ZPH007-0864475"  
data-val-required="Must be completed" data-val="true"
values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection
[System.String,System.Object]"
keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection
[System.String,System.Object]" count="3">
```

Currently I have it working for complex classes where the main return value should be 
Checkbox (nullable)
Currency (Nullable)
DateTime (nullable)
Radio Buttons list
Dropdown List (string)
Short text (textbox) and long text (TextArea).

I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: There is no prize, but who can spot the obvious mistake?  I'll give you a week.

Comment: That was way over a week but.... needs a parameterless constructor to post back.  Otherwise, it's great.  And the parameterless constructor (due to the implicit operator) writes directly into the "main" string property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Jquery, 
On form load ,this script will add validation to your preferred fields

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourId').rules("add", { required: true,messages:{required:"This is required field"} });
});
</script>
```

and if you want to remove any validation on any event then use

```
$('#yourId').rules("remove");
```

[See here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: While leaving your site open to server-side attack... since there is no server-side validation

Comment: Sever-side validation was not mentioned :/

Comment: Server side validation is always required, always.... you should never ever have only client-side validation.  That's just irresponsible programming.  Client-side Is optional, server-side never is.

Comment: This is an intranet application so server-side isn't as vital as it would otherwise be.  However, I wanted to validate via DataAnnotations so this isn't really the answer I was looking for.

Comment: So you can you use Mvc FoolProof Validation [See here](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Not without creating a seperate validator for every instance of MyTextBox - ie, every damn field on the form and there are over a hundred.  Each with different validation. 

EDIT - misread "Foolproof" as "Fluent" but Foolproof won't work either because my editors are not for direct strings, they are for data classes.

I'm working on a different solution right now.  If it works, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible solutions to this problem, and how you handle it depends greatly on a number of factors.

First, if you don't need client-side validation, you can always implement IValidatableObject on your model and do custom validation.  This is simple and straight forward, but doesn't give a very good end user experience.

Another option is to use something like FluentValidation, which allows you to write custom validators.

Yet another options Is to write custom DataAttributes, which implement their own client side validation interfaces.  You'll also have to include some custom javascript to configure the validators.

Another options is to simplify things, and create custom viewmodels with data attributes for each scenario.  This can quickly get messy if the number of options are large, but if it's manageable this is a relatively simple solution.

There are also some methods that require digging a lot deeper into the framework, which I won't go into here.. but I think you get the idea... You have to decide how you want to do validation and figure out the best approach.